# sed/awk: Insert some text in a file after the last pattern found

Tags: unix, sed, awk

I want to insert the text

```
#include < abc/malloc.h>
```

in a C file after all the

```
#include
```

lines, just after the last occurrence of `#include`.

Comment: Do you really want this to be the last `#include` or the last of the angle bracket includes? (Assuming a mixed implementation of `#include` with angle brankets and quotes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input:

```
$ cat in.h
#include <foo.h>
#include <bar.h>

/* No more includes */

/* But more stuff */
```

Find the last `#include` line:

```
$ l=$(grep -n '^#include' in.h | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1)
```

Append a line after this line:

```
$ sed "$l a#include <baz.h>" < in.h 
#include <foo.h>
#include <bar.h>
#include <baz.h>

/* No more includes */

/* But more stuff */
```

Comment: What if I want to append a newline \n at the end of #include <baz.h>?? Any idea how to do that? I'm using FreeBSD unix. I tried something like this but it didn't work: **sed "$l a#include <baz.h>\n" < in.h**. On STDOUT it displays with a newline but when I save STDOUT data to a file it becomes a one liner.

Comment: Suppose in.h contains:  
#include <foo.h> 
#include <bar.h> 
#define MIN 100   

Then in this case the output is as below:
#include <foo.h>
#include <bar.h> 
#include <baz.h>#define MIN 100 (baz.h and #define are printed at same line)

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read. If you have additional information, please edit your question.

Comment: I would use `$(grep  '^#include' in.h | wc -l)` instead of `$(grep -n '^#include' in.h | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1)`

Answer (score 3):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '
    FNR==NR && /^#include/ { line=NR; next }
    FNR!=NR
    FNR==line { print "#include <abc/malloc.h>" }
' code.c code.c
```

As you can see:

- `awk` read `code.c` twice
- first time if `FNR==NR`

Comment: Thanks! it works fine but how to make this change permanently in the file? I see code.c is not modified.

Comment: @Ashish `awk` doesn't modify the original file. you should redirect the stdout to a new file, then rename it to override the original file

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can have anything between includes.

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        x = 0
    }
    {
        if ($0 ~ /^#include/)
            x = NR
        b[NR]=$0
    }
    END {
        for (i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
            print b[i]
        print "#include <abc/malloc.h>"
        for (i = ++x; i <= NR; ++i)
            print b[i]
    }
' file.c
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
tac yourfile.c | sed '/#include/{ s/#include.*/#include<someheader>\n&/; :loop;n; t loop;}'| tac > updated_yourfile.c
```